# How to use an if statement with two conditions correctly in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, bitbucket

I have two small questions regarding my powershell script.

1. In the if-condition I want to query if either the "PostgreSQL Unicode" or the "PostgreSQL ODBC Driver(UNICODE)" is present. If one of these drivers is present then it should output "PostgreSQL ODBC drivers are already present".
   Unfortunately it asks first one and then the other. I.e. once it gives an error message and executes the source code from else and once it says "PostgreSQL ODBC drivers are already present". Question: why doesn't the script check both conditions combined? and why does it give an error message in case one although it should only execute the code from the else instead?
2. If I execute the script then everything works as desired. However, if I run the script on another computer then I get the error message "fatal: could not read Username for 'https://bitbucket.org': No such file or directory".
   How do I extend the script so that the script can clone the repositories on the BitBucket on all machines?

Powershell snipet:

```
#Git erlaubt remote für Powershell
git config --global credential.helper wincred

#ODBC Treiber werden hinzugefügt 
if ((Get-OdbcDriver -Name "PostgreSQL Unicode" -Platform '64-bit') -or (Get-OdbcDriver -Name "PostgreSQL ODBC Driver(UNICODE)" -Platform '64-bit'))
{
Write-Host "PostgreSQL ODBC Treiber sind bereits vorhanden" -ForegroundColor White
}
```

Error Question 1:

```
Get-OdbcDriver : Es wurde kein Treiber gefunden.
In C:\Users\****\****** 
AG\Dokumente\Arbeitsunterlagen\Skripte\Powershell\UpdateRepositories&Database.ps1:11 Zeichen:6
+ if ((Get-OdbcDriver -Name "PostgreSQL Unicode" -Platform '64-bit') -o ...
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSFT_OdbcDriverTask:Root/Microsoft/..._OdbcDriverTas 
   k) [Get-OdbcDriver], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 6,Get-OdbcDriver
PostgreSQL ODBC Treiber sind bereits vorhanden
```

Error Question 2:

```
git : bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
In C:\Users\*******\Downloads\UpdateRepositories&Database.ps1:53 Zeichen:1
+ git clone https://bitbucket.org/*****/database.git - ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (bash: /dev/tty:...vice or address:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://bitbucket.org': No such file or directory
git : bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
In C:\Users\*****\Downloads\UpdateRepositories&Database.ps1:62 Zeichen:1
+ git clone https://bitbucket.org/****/service.git -- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (bash: /dev/tty:...vice or address:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Comment: Add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to the `Get-OdbcDriver` call(s) to make them fail silently

Comment: Thanks Mathias, first problem solved :)

Comment: The second error looks like the result of the unfortunate fact that you cannot run _interactive_ console applications in remote PowerShell sessions.